# Update data in different tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a table I have the following schema

```
table1:
playerID int primary key,
nationalities nvarchar

table2:
playerID int,
pubVisited nvarchar
```

Now, I want to set all the players' playedVisited to null, for player whose nationality is "England", any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tested on SQL Server 2005

```
update table2 set pubVisited = NULL 
from 
    table1 t1 
        inner join 
    table2 t2 
    on (t1.playerID = t2.playerID and t1.nationalities = 'England')
```

Comment: I've been malaccustomed. I tend to use the implicit inner join syntax. In other words, that IS an inner join.

Comment: I found that using implicit inner join syntax is a bad practice. Please see this blog https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins So, we must **avoid using the old ANSI-89 JOIN syntax**

Comment: That's why I said "malaccustomed". I really don't find the arguments in that post particularly convincing, though.

Answer (score 3):

Judging by the *nvarchar* type, you're using MSSQL. Now, in MySQL you could use a subselect in the update .. where clause but MSSQL has its own update .. from clause:

```
UPDATE table2
SET
    table2.pubVisited = null
FROM table1
WHERE
    table2.playerID = table1.playerID and table1.nationalities = 'England'
```

Haven't tested it though, so it might not work.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax in Oracle would be:

```
update table2
set playedvisited = NULL
where playerID in (select playerID 
                   from table1 
                   where nationalities = 'England')
```